# Jenkins Build Failure because of Ui Tests (Selenium)

Tags: selenium, jenkins, gwt, deployment, build

I've got the following problem:

1. One GWT application(internet shop) with unit Tests and selenium UI Tests (automated)
2. One jenkins server where i can build my application (new version number or snapshot)

The failure:

The build on jenkins doesn't work because ui Tests can't run (The application needs to be deployed at that moment)

How can jenkins deploy the programm at that moment, so the application can run the selenium tests?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jenkins to model your pipeline, which in its most basic setup will have, three stages which should be defined in a `Jenkinsfile`. Simple Declarative Pipeline example:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo 'Building'
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                echo 'Testing'
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                echo 'Deploying'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In your case, *after* Unit tests pass, you can promote your Application to higher environment, like QA and trigger UI tests. If utilized properly, this setup will be very handy as [Staging/Production phase](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/deployment/#stages-as-deployment-environments).